# ExecutorService using inside a rest API

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have a API, which is doing four tasks. If we do sequential this API will take more time.
To increase the performance I have used Executor service framework and submitted four task using executor service.

As i know creating thread is expensive operation, and in executor service thread will be created at the time of submitting the tasks. And threads will be destroyed when we call shutdown method of executor service.

This is the process of each request in this scenario :

1. API call
2. create executor service
3. submit the four future task
4. Create the response from all return threads.
5. call shutdown executor service method.
6. return the response

So my question is creating executor service and threads in each request is correct or not? Or please let me know alternative solution of this.

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s not wise to terminate and re-instantiate ExecutorService frequently. That’s the whole point of it. Create a fixed thread pool as you already know the number of tasks you want to carry out in parallel. Also decouple your request handler from creation of ExecutorService. Note, you’re calling shutdown(), meaning finish the current tasks and do not accept any new tasks, it’s not reusable, it forces you to reinstate the pool per request, so try not to terminate the thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to use a thread pool to parallelize processing of incoming requests. But it's not fine to create a new thread pool on each API call.

In order to do this right, you should create a separate `ExecutorService` instance and simply reuse it, and shutdown it only when you shutdown the application.

Also, remember about sizing it properly because if it gets saturated, it will degrade your latency instead of improving it.

Comment: If i create executor service with four threads, before the request come. During multiple call to API, first call will be using all four threads to executing the four tasks, and meanwhile all the other request will be waiting.

Comment: Yes, this is why I added a note about sizing it properly.

Comment: That i agree creating and destroying executor service in each API call is wrong. Sizing of thread pool in this scenario is not easy, or is thread pool executor is not for this context ? Because, for example if we hit rest API 1000 time then what will be the size of thread pool, or if this number increase to 10 million then what will be the thread pool size.

Comment: @DeepakGusain actually,it's quite easy if you know non-functional requirements for the service

Comment: It's better to saturate the `ExecutorService` than to consume 100% cpu resources and degrade the performance of the entire system.

Answer (score -1):

Create a singleton of your `ExecutorService` and use that same instance for all requests.  DO NOT create it over and over again.  You should also limit the maximum number of threads owned by the `ExecutorService` to prevent your REST API from blowing up your server.